get response after being redirected
I'm just trying to change my request location without using any kind of proxies, I was ended up with the following URL which is working perfectly in the browser and selenium library (python).
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004753962000.html?sourceType=620&_randl_shipto=DZ&gatewayAdapt=4itemAdapt

my question is there any way to do that using requests library, I tried to do that with sessions but it does not want to work.

Show us what you have tried so far, in code. It might also make clearer what you are actually asking.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
